# Listeners report distorted sound when I call with Skype

Tags: sound, skype

I'm using Skype on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS and for the past several weeks, when I call someone, they say they can't understand me because the sound is very distorted. I hear them just fine, though. I suspect this may be related to an Ubuntu update because nothing changed on the Skype side, as far as I know. Has anyone had the same problem? It's so bad that now I need to use my Pixel 2 when calling with Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Poor VOIP quality on outgoing audio only is usually due to you (or other computers on your network) having maxed out your Internet connection's capacity to send data out. For most, available upstream bandwidth may be only 10 to 20% of your downstream bandwidth. Before you blame your computer, is another computer using Skype experiencing the same troubles at the same time you are?  Any program that syncs with a cloud account might be responsible for maxing outgoing bandwidth, especially if it is for sync'd folders or online-backup.

The fix is to have your firewall/router prioritize VOIP traffic over most other traffic. Many consumer routers have an option for QoS or VOIP prioritization, though they often are not very clear about how it's being implemented. Skype being fairly popular, hopefully most would succeed in prioritizing it. If you really want to get into the nuts and bolts of QoS, consider [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) (an open-source firewall) and its 'traffic shaping' options.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the problem only occurs on my laptop; Skype on my Pixel 2 phone using the same Internet connection has no problem.

Comment: actually, you did say that. :)
Q: when switching to Pixel: Notebook Skype failing, Pixel working:  Is notebook still on, network connected, and running same tasks it was when Skype failed?
I have a hard time believing the trouble is w notebook (and not total network traffic). Perhaps you've already tried some of this:  Have you tried:
 1) connecting your notebook with wired network and temporarily disconnecting everything else from the network, and closing everything but Skype on your notebook.
 2) from an other network:  at work, public wifi, a neighbor's network.